# Assign one array to another Classic asp

Tags: arrays, asp-classic

I'm pretty new to classic asp and working with arrays is not fun :(

I keep getting an error on

```
            dim isMyApiResponse

            if MyAvailRooms = "Error" then
                isMyApiResponse = false
            else
                isMyApiResponse = true
                dim MyAvailArray()

                If InStr( MyAvailRooms, "," ) > 1 Then 
                    'response.write("<h2>MyAvailRooms is " & MyAvailRooms)
                    'response.write("<h2>var type of My avil rooms is " & VarType(MyAvailRooms))
                    MyAvailRooms = CStr(MyAvailRooms)
                    dim tempArray
                    tempArray = split(MyAvailRooms, ",")

                    dim sizeTempArray
                    sizeTempArray = UBound(tempArray)

                    response.write ("<h2>type of sizeTempArray is " &VarType(MyAvailArray))
                    response.write("<br/>type of temp array is " & VarType(tempArray))

                    reDim MyAvailArray(sizeTempArray)
                    MyAvailArray  = tempArray

                else 
                    ReDim MyAvailArray(1)
                    MyAvailArray (0) = MyAvailRooms
                end if
            end if
```

I'm getting a type mismatch on the line "**MyAvailArray  = tempArray**" above. I guess it's a dynamic fixed array problem or something. Both types are coming back as 8204 in my reponse.write, which is variant I think.

I'm at the end of my tether, please help me Classic ASP ninjas!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I am not able to explain why this throws an error:

```
MyAvailArray = tempArray
```

You can loop through each array element and assign them one-by-one and it should work ;)

```
Dim i
for i = 0 to sizeTempArray
    MyAvailArray(i) = tempArray(i)
next
```

Comment: The reason for the error is because dynamic array is not static array and one can't be cast to the other directly.

Answer (score 1):

I've always had trouble declaring dynamic arrays using the `Dim myArray()` syntax.  I always declare my arrays as regular variants, which still allows me to use the `ReDim` statement later on.

(As a side note, if I need an empty array, I'll use the `Array` function with no arguments, i.e. `myArray = Array()`.  The benefit there is that calling the `UBound` function will return -1 instead of giving an error, so I can easily determine if an array is empty.)

```
Dim MyAvailArray

If InStr( MyAvailRooms, "," ) > 1 Then
    '<snip>'
    MyAvailArray = tempArray
Else 
    MyAvailArray = Array(MyAvailRooms)
End If
```

Note that I used the `Array` function for brevity.

---

By the way, the `InStr` check is unnecessary, since `Split` will always return an array, even if the separator isn't in the string.  Therefore, you could rewrite the code as:

```
Dim MyAvailArray
MyAvailArray = Split(MyAvailRooms, ",")
```